# how to use C# module in window store javascript project using windows 8 and phonegap 2.2

Tags: cordova, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, cordova-2.0.0

I have created a window store (javascript) project using phone gap 2.2 in windows 8 & visual studio 2012.

I need to create a page which will send an audio file to a service(outside scope). This audio file will be picked by user at runtime.

Please advice how do i pick file using javascript, if its not possible then please advice how i can create a c# module and include that in my javascript project

thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Seems [File picker sample (JavaScript)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba) is what you are looking for

The sample demonstrates these tasks:

```
Let the user pick one file to access

Uses the FileOpenPicker . PickSingleFileAsync method to call a file picker window and let the user pick a single file. For a walkthrough of this task, see Quickstart: accessing files with file pickers.
```

If you still would like to include some C# modules, then take a look on the following

[Walkthrough: Creating a simple component in C# or Visual Basic and calling it from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)